# $.each in function undefined (without works)

Tags: javascript, json

There was a problem with JSON output using a function. I need something like this:

```
function loadnames()
{
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "<?php echo $servers; ?>",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function() {
            console.log('All right');
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('Cry baby');
        }
    }).responseText;
}

function srvName(sid) {
    var names = JSON.parse(loadnames());
    $.each(names.data.servers, function(index, server) {
        if(server.id == sid) {
            return server.hostname;
        }
    }); 
}

alert(srvName(86));
```

But it does not work. If you remove the sid from the function and put it manually, then everything works and displays what you need ... How to fix this thing?

This works:

```
function srvName() {
    var names = JSON.parse(loadnames());
    $.each(names.data.servers, function(index, server) {
        if(server.id == 86) {
            return server.hostname;
        }
    }); 
}

alert(srvName());
//returns SERVER NAME 86 from alert
```

Json example:

```
{
  "data": {
    "servers":[
        {
            "id":86,
            "hostname":"SERVER NAME 86"
            },
            {
            "id":23,
            "hostname":"SERVER NAME 23"
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

Comment: use .equals instead of ==

Comment: Your `srvName` function doesn't return anything. It's returned value is `undefined`. The `return server.hostname;` line sets the return value of your `$.each` callback. You may want to use the `Array.prototype.find` method for filtering one item of an array instead of `$.each`. Something like `return names.data.servers.find(...)`

Comment: @VinuBibin this isn't Java...what are you going to do `.equals` on or against?

Comment: @vinubibin, Thanks, I will try) But this will not solve my problem)

Comment: @Xhonor don't listen to that - it's a nonsensical advice. undefined (the user) is correct - you aren't *returning* anything from your `srvName` function - the `return` statement is inside the callback given to `$.each`

Comment: @undefined, I tried using callback, but I have a datatable with 10000+ entries where I need to replace in the ID column with the Server name. :)
The table does not cope and gives null in the column.

Comment: reading this `async: false` bothers me; plus many browsers have deprecated synchronous requests. You need to take a look into async programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace your code with the following:-

```
function srvName(sid) {
    var names = JSON.parse(loadnames());
    if(names.data.servers) {
      let server = names.data.servers.find(server => server.id === sid);
      if(server) return server.hostname;
      return 'matching server not found';
    }
}

alert(srvName(86));
```

Comment: You forgot to add ; after return :)

Comment: Yeah. but that is no more a mandate for running javascript. You can omit all semicolons

Comment: If i use ur code in Datatable render, Console displayed error: Cannot read property 'hostname' of undefined.

Comment: Edited with validation. You can tweak it to your use case

Comment: Everything is working. But the table loads 5 minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `filter` and `map` functions together to achieve what you need.

See below -

```js
var myJason = `{
  "data": {
    "servers":[
        {
            "id":86,
            "hostname":"SERVER NAME 86"
            },
            {
            "id":23,
            "hostname":"SERVER NAME 23"
        }
      ]
    }
}`;

function srvName() {
    var names = JSON.parse(myJason);
    return names.data.servers.filter(f=> f.id==86).map(f=> f.hostname);
}

console.log(srvName());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note - Since alert only displays `string` that is why you will need to `stringify` it in order to view it in alert.

Comment: It's a bit wasteful to do `filter` -> `map` in this case. One would assume that there would be a single server with a given ID, so doing a full scan of the array to find it instead of exiting early is not needed. Second, this will create *two* new arrays when all you need is a single string. `.find(predicate).hostname` with a null guard is way more straight forward and efficient.

Comment: @vlaz, You are correct. I think someone has already answered with `find`.